# TestLink and Jenkins Test Case not run

Tags: maven, jenkins, testcase, testlink

I have three test cases in TestLink and when I build the maven project, using Jenkins, none of the tests case is run, the project is built correctly but the test cases aren't run. I am using JUnit for the tests. I am new to this so I am not sure what the problem is.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are your test cases located? How they are named? How does the pom file look like?